# How can I plot only one column in an R dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I am only interested in a column called 'chol'. How can I plot a box plot of only the column named 'chol'?. Here is the code I have so far but it is not working:

```
heart_health<-(C"://Users//H//heart.health.csv")
chol<-heart_health[,5,drop=FALSE]
library(ggplot2)
p<-gpglot(x,chol(x=dose,y=len))+
geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: looking at your code,  in your ```ggplot()``` you are defining data as ```x``` that you have not named in your code, also you have 1 column, how would you have a ```x``` and a ```y```, in there?
the default for ggplot() is ```ggplot(data, aes(x,y)``` where data is your dataframe to get the x and y axis out from.

Answer (score 2):

next time, please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data. It makes it easier to reproduce and solve your individual problem.
However, using `ggplot2` makes it easy to plot a certain column of your data by defining the `y` argument in `aes()` (note that the y-axis in a boxplot contains the quantity of the variable you want to plot). I think there are some issues with your `ggplot2` code. I generated some random data for illustration:

```
df <- data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(100, 50, 20),
  col2 = rnorm(100, 20, 10)
)

> head(df)
      col1      col2
1 33.63978  5.417414
2 72.03567 12.969431
3 51.16503 -4.484358
4 42.03396 20.001371
5 19.73810 27.522977
6 38.02925 38.287728
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(y=col1)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: I was unaware that the ```x``` could be ingnored in the ```aes()``` when boxplots are involved, learned something today.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. 
In the case of boxplots, defining `x` is useful to stratify the plot by a grouping variable. If you are interested, [here are some examples how to do this](https://r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html).